# Why is httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode returned as false? From an API to ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, connection, httpclient

I have 3-tier project, I do database / API / MVC on ASP.NET Core; all controllers are working correctly but this connection of this API controller doesn't work.

This is my business layer function:

```
    public List<Ticket> ViewTickets()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new MaintenanceSysContext(_options))
            {
                List<Ticket> tickets = null;
                List<int> ticketsId = db.Tickets.SelectMany(t => t.backOfficesTickets).Where(u => u.BackOfficeId == _backOfficeEntry.GetUserId()).Select(t => t.TicketId).ToList();
              
                foreach( var i in ticketsId)
                {
                    tickets = db.Tickets.Where(t => t.Id == i).ToList();
                }

                if (tickets != null)
                {
                    return tickets;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And this is the controller in the API:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("[action]")]
    [ActionName("ViewTickets")]
    public IActionResult  ViewTickets()
    {
        var tickets = _buildingManager.ViewTickets();
        return Ok(tickets);
    }
```

Here's my ASP.NET Core MVC `httpClient` connection:

url base:

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public static string baseUrl = "http://localhost:16982/api/BuildingManagerAPI/";
```

ASP.NET Core MVC controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetTickets()
{
    List<Ticket> TicketList = new List<Ticket>();

    using (client)
    {
        var accessToken = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Token");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl + "ViewTickets");

        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            TicketList = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Ticket>>();
        }
    }
    
    return Json(TicketList, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In the `httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode` I get back a value of `false` while API works correctly AND returns a proper response when testing in Postman. I don't know what the problem of my connection is.

**UPDATE:**

Postman request output:

```
[
{
    "Id": 1,
    "BeneficiaryID": 4,
    "BeneficiaryUser": null,
    "backOfficesTickets": null,
    "StatusID": 2,
    "status": null,
    "ApprovalState": 2,
    "Date": "2021-08-22T00:00:00",
    "Picture": null,
    "MaintenanceTypeID": 1,
    "maintenanceType": null,
    "Description": "krng",
    "BuildingManagerComment": null,
    "FloorId": 1,
    "floor": null,
    "IsCancelled": false,
    "CancellationReasonID": null,
    "cancelationReason": null,
    "RejectedBy": null,
    "UserRejected": null,
    "RejectionReason": null,
    "CreatedBy": 4,
    "CreatedTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "UpdatedBy": 0,
    "UpdatedTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "IsDeleted": false
}
```

Red Point doesn't get uri (client base uri=null) then IsSuccessStatusCode set as NULL.

Comment: Have you set a break point and inspected the `httpResponse`? You should be able to get an exception message or some other information from that to determine at least a starting point for the problem at hand. No one on here is going to be able to determine the issue based on the information you provided.

Comment: Can you also please post a picture of postman output along with the final request ?

Comment: `In the httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode I get back a value of false` What is the _exact_ status code?

Comment: `foreach( var i in ticketsId)
                {
                    tickets = db.Tickets.Where(t => t.Id == i).ToList();
                }` This is a _very_ weird loop. It is either wrong, or super inefficient, depending on what you expect it to do.

Comment: What was the response code on `PostMan`?

Comment: @mjwills yes it's wrong thank you i correct it but still connection has error

Comment: `In the httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode I get back a value of false` What is the exact status code?

Comment: Share your exact error code please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Problem Was in Token (Doesn't carry claim) we fix it. Thanks For All.

Answer (score 0):

try to add an accept header

```
....
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```